# What does it mean that UST10 have risen from 1.2 to greater than 1.7 over the last half year?

Tags: bonds, treasury, yield-curve

I'm a newbe in bonds market, but I'd like to ask what does it indicate that UST10 have risen from 1.2 to greater than 1.7 over the last half year?

Does it mean that the bond market foresees high inflation in the next decade or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that the bond market foresees high inflation in the next decade or what?

Not necessarily inflation, but the market thinks that *interest rates* (meaning the interest rates that the Federal Reserve charges) will be higher over the next 10 years than it did 6 months ago. Inflation is related but not necessarily tied to interest rates, so it's not a direct reflection of inflation expectations.